# How to remove ripple effect from Collection view item in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, collectionview

I have a collection view in my Xamarin forms project. in iOS it is working fine But in Android I am getting a ripple effect when I select item from collection view.And the selection mode is single. How can I remove this ripple effect from android. Please help.

Comment: You mean you want the only selection background color right?

Comment: Yes, I don't need that animation.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been reported and fixed. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/7615

It would remove ripple effect on CollectionView item when SelectionMode is None.

Comment: my selection mode is single.

Comment: You could refer to the link below. Create a custom renderer to reset with selector. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/177763/how-to-remove-ripple-effect-from-collection-view